# Compiling Haiku OS for mobile devices

Tags: compilation, operating-system, mobile-phones, haiku

Is it possible for me to compile [Haiku OS](http://haiku-os.org/) (a BeOS descendant) for mobile devices, for example, a phone? If yes, has anybody done it yet? Are there any examples?

Answer (score 1):

At this stage it's not possible, unless you find a phone with an x86 chip in it of course ;)

There have been attempts to port the kernel to the ARM architecture and this would be the first stage in the process, devices such as the DS, some phones etc. use ARM chips. However I can't see it running on an ARM machine in the near future (read: 1-2 years) and even then there would be so many more things required - support for the phone features for instance.

For now all the effort is being spent getting it ready for the desktop, and rightfully so!

Comment: LOL!  An x86 phone can sure heat up your soup fast!